# Generating a sheet and naming it incrementally on Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

The program below basically summons a modal popup that asks for a sheet #. When a value is added, it changes the name of the current sheet name "RCdisb (OpEx) : Current" to "RCdisb (OpEx) : Sheet #1" when the script runs. After this, It then creates another sheet and names it to "RCdisb (OpEx) : Current" following a template.

Now my problem is I am limited to Sheet #1 as for some reason my rcdisbopex = 1 does not increment the value when running the script.

The goal that I want to have is when I create a sheet and it changes the current sheets name, I would like the changed name to follow a number order from 1 - 10 (Ex. Sheet #1, Sheet #2, etc.)

```
function newOpex(){
const ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
var rcdisbopex = 1;
var result = ui.prompt(
      ' Create New Operating Expense Sheet',
      'Please enter Sheet Number:',
      ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);

  // Process the user's response.
  var button = result.getSelectedButton();
  var text = result.getResponseText()
  if (button == ui.Button.OK) {
    // User clicked "OK".
  var newOpexName = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("RCDisb (OpEx) : Current").setName("RCDisb (OpEx) : Sheet #"+ rcdisbopex);
  var newOpexSheet = newOpexName.getSheetName();
  Logger.log(newOpexSheet);
  rcdisbopex++;
  var templateSheet = ws.getSheetByName('templateOpEx');
  ws.insertSheet('RCDisb (OpEx) : Current', 2, {template: templateSheet});
  var sheetName = ('RCDisb (OpEx) : Current');
  Logger.log(sheetName);
  Utilities.sleep(1000)

  } else if (button == ui.Button.CANCEL) {
    // User clicked "Cancel".
    ui.alert('⚠️Operation Cancelled.');
  } else if (button == ui.Button.CLOSE) {
    // User clicked X in the title bar.
    ui.alert('⚠️You closed the dialog.');
  }
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  ss.getRange(9, 8, 1, 1).setValue(text)
  ss.getRange(8, 8, 1, 1).setValue(text)
  ss.getRange(5, 6, 1, 1).setValue("Period Covered: "+ date)
}
```

Comment: In your script, `ws` is not declared. But, you say `Now my problem is I am limited to Sheet #1 as for some reason my rcdisbopex = 1 does not increment the value when running the script.`. So, I'm worried that you have miscopied your script. How about this?

Comment: oh im sorry! it was a piece of my script. my bad will update it now

Comment: Why not write the value of `rcdisbopex++` to a given cell? In any event, the reason that it doesn't increment is because of `var rcdisbopex = 1` - you are setting the value at 1.